# Django: infinite redirects in cookie-setting code?

Tags: django, http, cookies

This cookie-setting/redirecting Django views code is resulting in a redirect loop, even for browsers with cookies enabled. Can anyone explain how to fix it?

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', 'library.views.home', name="home"),
url(r'^ldap/(?P<next>[\w-]*)/$', 'library.views.update_session_from_ldap', name="ldap"),
```

In views.py:

```
def home(request):
    print 'home'
    current_user = request.COOKIES.get('ldap_user', None)
    print current_user
    if not current_user:
        return redirect('/ldap', next='/')
    print 'now here'
# url = '/ldap'
def update_session_from_ldap(request, next):
    remote_user = request.META.get('REMOTE_USER', None)
    hrr = HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    hrr.set_cookie('ldap_user', remote_user)
    print 'set cookie!'
    return hrr
```

I just see...

```
home
None
[04/Apr/2011 23:21:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
set cookie!
[04/Apr/2011 23:21:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
set cookie!
[04/Apr/2011 23:21:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
set cookie!... ad infinitum until the browser intervenes
```

If I reload the page a second time, it is OK: the print statement shows the correct value and there is no redirect, so the cookie is working. It's just the first time the code runs that it goes into an infinite loop.

Any ideas? Any better ways to solve this problem?

The problem is the same in Firefox and Chrome.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I think the problem is in the way that the URLs are configured: I need to work out a way to go from 'home' to 'ldap' and back again, somehow. I think at the moment 'ldap' is just redirecting to itself.

Comment: OK, I think I get it - the problem isn't actually the views code per se, it's the URLs, which I'm really struggling with. I've updated with the URLs, can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried setting a default for your next? I think that you might not be matching your regex and sending None to your view.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like your regex will match a `/`:

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^ldap/(?P<next>[\w-]*)/$', 'library.views.update_session_from_ldap', name="ldap"),
```

**views.py:**

```
def update_session_from_ldap(request, next):
    if next is None:
        hrr = HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        hrr = HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    remote_user = request.META.get('REMOTE_USER', None)
    hrr.set_cookie('ldap_user', remote_user)
    print 'set cookie!'
    return hrr
```